# Check Exchange user authorizations with EWS

Tags: authorization, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

how could I check with EWS which permissions (FULL ACCESS or only SEND AS)
 a user has  on a mailbox ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't those rights are assigned at the Store level and EWS because its a Mailbox Access API can only read the DACL's on Mailbox folders.

Cheers
Glen